# sql oracle query group by issue

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, ora-00979

```
select e.EMPNO, e.EMPNAME ,e.DEPT_NO, d.DEPT_NAME
 FROM EMPLOYEE e , DEPARTMENT d
  WHERE e.DEPT_NO = d.DEPT_NO 
GROUP BY d.DEPT_NO;
```

ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression

Comment: Barbaros Özhan
Can you please explain or share the query , thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi . This is a very famous and common error in Oracle's SQL. I've just added more duplicate questions already answered each will explain what you need. Farewell.